# iOS Change UIView content at runtime

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, uistoryboard, xib

I have three UIViews that span the width of the screen and each take up a third of the screen vertically.  The center UIView contains a form that the user fills out.  I have several forms that I need to switch out of the center UIView.  Right now in the storyboard I have each of the UIViews sitting between the top and bottom UIViews and I hide the views depending on user selections.  Is there a better way of doing this?  Maybe have just one center view and changing the content via XIBs?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your forms are small enough that approach is probably fine. By small enough I mean they don't have much (ideally any) business logic / validations etc inside them.

However, if your forms have validation and other things that don't really belong in the view layer you could embed a ViewController per form to handle the logic?

I would look at using a [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library//ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html) to contain these, and an embed segue in your storyboard io embed the page controller into your storyboard.

This is quite a bit more work, so it's worth thinking about whether it's worth the effort. It's benefits are modularity and testability - you won't end up with a single view controller with *all* your code in :) You can also take advantage of the memory optimisations that UIPageViewController will do for you. And it will handle transitions between the forms, though I don't know if they will be the transitions you want :)

The drawback is architectural complexity.

Comment: The UIViewController handles all operations including validations.  I don't think the UIPageViewController is going to work because they want the three views to be visible on the screen with maybe a little scrolling.  The storyboard is just getting large and it's a lot of work to add a new section.

Comment: Ah, sorry - I thought only one would be visible and you were toggling between them. You're right, UIPageViewController won't help you at all! In that case you could still use a UIViewController per form and just add the views yourself manually to a scroll view with `paging=YES`?

Comment: I wish I could go that route.  It would be easier.  Thanks.